# Where to ask questions about external sites (like Google accounts)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, area-51, login, user-accounts

Today, I had a question about Google accounts. So, I went to stackexchange.com/sites and scoured for a possible site to ask about external unrelated sites. I searched and searched for minutes, but I could not find one.

So: here are my two questions:

**1. Where do I ask questions about a product like Google, or [Wix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wix.com) usability?**

and

**2. Where do I ask questions about which no site exists?**

Now, about the latter: I know that I can simply create a site-request on Area 51, but sometimes one just doesn't has enough time to wait three days (at minimum).

P.S.: I accidentally wrote this with the wrong account, meaning I accidentally signed up for a wrong one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Where do I ask questions about a product like Google, or Wix usability?

Checkout https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> 2. Where do I ask questions about which no site exists?

Not on Stack Exchange Network.

Answer (score 3):

To quote their help page, [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags) is the place for questions abuot:

> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application

Specifically, both Google and Wix have tags there.

Answer (score 3):

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) would appear to be a viable option for you. It has a [wix.com](/questions/tagged/wix.com) [tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) and various [google](/questions/tagged/google) tags depending on what exactly you want to ask.

As always, read the site's [help centre first](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) to check that your question is likely to be well received there and check whether it's already asked.